# Clone git repository with --recursive and --bare

Tags: git, git-submodules

In order to clone a repository and all of its submodules I know you can do this:

```
$ git clone --recursive <url>
```

You can also clone a repository to a bare repository using this:

```
$ git clone --bare <url>
```

I want to recursively clone to bare repositories, so I tried this:

```
$ git clone --bare --recursive git@github.com:boostorg/boost.git
```

Which only clones the first repository (none of the submodules).

How can I recursively clone to bare repositories?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to go to each individual submodules directory and clone them. The concept of submodules is to incorporate 3rd party modules which will only be used.